Debug Xcode Custom Keyboard Extension

I currently have a React Native + Expo Go app, and I run a native build in Xcode. My original Podfile (Figure 1) works correctly and compiles without issues.

My team is trying to integrate our app into an iOS Custom Keyboard Extension. See example in figure 1. The original podfile compiles and works even with the keyboard extension added.  However, the problems begin when I try to import the React module to KeyboardViewControl objective-C and header files.

Imports:



#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>



Build Error:


I encountered build errors after importing some React headers and updating the Podfile to the structure shown in Figure 2.


I have tried various Podfile configurations and imports, but I keep encountering different errors depending on the structure.

Figure 1: Sample keyboard extension:

Figure 2: Original Working podfile without extensions:

require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")


require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}


ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']


platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
 :deterministic_uuids => false


prepare_react_native_project!


target 'AppPrototype' do
 use_expo_modules!
 config = use_native_modules!


 # changed re https://rnfirebase.io/#altering-cocoapods-to-use-frameworks
 use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
 use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
 # use_frameworks! :linkage => :static


 pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true


 $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true






 use_react_native!(
   :path => config[:reactNativePath],
   :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
   # An absolute path to your application root.
   :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
   # Temporarily disable privacy file aggregation by default, until React
   # Native 0.74.2 is released with fixes.
   :privacy_file_aggregation_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.privacyManifestAggregationEnabled'] == 'true',
 )


 post_install do |installer|
   react_native_post_install(
     installer,
     config[:reactNativePath],
     :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
     :ccache_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.ccacheEnabled'] == 'true',
   )


   # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
   # when building for devices.
   installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
     .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
     target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
       resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
       end
     end
   end
 end


 post_integrate do |installer|
   begin
     expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
   rescue => e
     Pod::UI.warn e
   end
 end
end


Figure 3: New podfile with extension target:
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")


require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}


ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']


platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
 :deterministic_uuids => false


prepare_react_native_project!


target 'AppPrototype' do
 use_expo_modules!
 config = use_native_modules!


 use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
 use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']


 pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true


 $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true


 use_react_native!(
   :path => config[:reactNativePath],
   :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
   :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
   :privacy_file_aggregation_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.privacyManifestAggregationEnabled'] == 'true',
 )
end


target 'SymbolGridExt_v1' do
 use_expo_modules!
 config = use_native_modules!
 pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
 pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true


 use_react_native!(
   :path => config[:reactNativePath],
   :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
   :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
 )


 pre_install do |installer|
   installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
     if pod.name.include?('Firebase') || pod.name.include?('GoogleUtilities') || pod.name.include?('FirebaseCoreInternal') ||    pod.name.include?('FirebaseCore')
       pod.target_definitions.each do |target_definition|
         if target_definition.name == 'SymbolGridExt_v1'
           target_definition.dependencies.delete_if { |dep| dep.name == pod.name }
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end


end


post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   if target.name == 'SymbolGridExt_v1'
     # Remove Firebase and Google utilities for SymbolGridExt_v1 target
     target.dependencies.delete_if { |dependency|
       dependency.name.include?('Firebase') ||
       dependency.name.include?('GoogleUtilities') ||
       dependency.name.include?('FirebaseCoreInternal') ||
       dependency.name.include?('FirebaseCore')
     }
   end
 end


 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React/**', '$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/**']
     config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'RCT_ENABLE_INSPECTOR=1', 'RCT_REMOTE_PROFILE=1']
   end
 end


 installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results.each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
   target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
     resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
     end
   end
 end


 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React/**', '$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/**']
   end
 end
end



Update: after applying a patch from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39903#issuecomment-2023618583 I now get a new error related to React-Fabric: Codegen did not run properly in your project. Please reinstall cocoapods with bundle exec pod install. 
